# FloatingActionButton shadow not being drawn properly

Tags: android

I am using FloatingActionButton - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html
Randomly I see that the shadow is not being drawn properly - it comes out in solid grey as opposed to a gradient.

Here is my markup:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/fabButton"
    android:src="@drawable/search"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Has anybody else faced this?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you forgot these attributes:

```
...
app:elevation="6dp"
app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
...
```

See this answer for more information about [FloatingActionButton design guides](http://FloatingActionButton%20design%20guides)